# debian/watch for Fedora

Tags: fedora, rhel, package-management

How do Fedora maintainers track new versions of upstream package sources? Is there anything like [debian/watch](https://wiki.debian.org/debian/watch/) in the Fedora/Red Hat world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the following topic in the Fedora Project's Wiki which covers this:

- [Tracking upstream projects](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Tracking_upstream_projects)

Also there is additional information if you look through the category ["Packages Maintainers"](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Category%3aPackage_Maintainers?rd=PackageMaintainers) as well.

Comment: Looks like Fedora doesn't have any package specific files. Everything is conta

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: Fedora uses https://release-monitoring.org/ webapp that emits notifications through `fedmsg` so subscribed services catch them and react (e.g. create ticket in RedHat bugzilla about new versions).

---

- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upstream_release_monitoring

Looks like Fedora [package specification](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package) doesn't contain fields that replace debian/watch file to track new upstream releases. All rules are collected and read directly from the wiki page, and only if package maintainer itself added rule. Using these strings [Robot](http://fedorapeople.org/cgit/till/public_git/cnucnu.git/tree/) automatically checks and generates tickets in Fedora tracker when a new release is detected. The downside is that you lose the ability to run [uscan](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=1&query=uscan&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en) locally or get a summary like the one you can get from [UDD](https://wiki.debian.org/UltimateDebianDatabase).